# how to make `redux-saga` use the result of the latest dispatched event?

Tags: redux-saga

I have an input field and every time the `value` changed, I dispatched an event to fetch a backend API using the value. But the APIs' response time varies: A later fetched API may return responses before a former fetched API, which makes the last response not corresponding to the latest value.

I am using `redux-saga` middleware, and want to know whether `redux-saga` provides a way to manage the responses so that I can using the response corresponding to the latest dispatched event?

I need the action be dispatched immediately, and the responses to be processed in order.

Comment: use `takeLatest`, see: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args

Comment: No, they are different problems.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Normally we just need latest result, `takeLatest` will cancel prev unfinished task, so only latest response will dispatch.

Comment: To make it clear, the latest result not need to be the response corresponding to the latest dispatched event. e.g. Event A is dispatched at time 0s, takes 2s to return; event B is dispatched at time 0.5s, takes 1s to return; so B returns before A. If A and B are same kind of events, how to make sure the response to event B being processed after A?

Comment: So you want prev response block later response?

Comment: I want prev response(response to B) processed later than the response to A.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is redux-saga [channels](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md) effect and [buffers](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#buffers)

TL:DR

```
import { buffers } from 'redux-saga'
import { take, actionChannel, call, ... } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchActions() {
    // 1- Create a channel for queueing actions
    const actionsChannel = yield actionChannel('REQUEST', buffers. expanding(5))

    while (true) {
        // 2- Blocks the Saga until a message is available on the channel
        const {payload} = yield take(actionsChannel)
        // 3- Note that we're using a blocking call
        yield call(handleRequest, payload)
    }
}

function* handleRequest(payload) { ... }
```

Explanation: The code above uses the redux-saga channel effect to queue actions by the order they've been dispatched (using a buffer) if the saga is no ready to take them yet (e.g. blocked on an API call).